# Update Single Column with Values from Another Table Column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table X. I want to update Column X in this table with a value from a column in table Y. The columns are the same but there is no join on these tables. I have written a select to get the IDs from table Y. I am just not sure how to update the table X records with each value from the select.

It does not matter which ID goes where because it mock data anyways. I just want to populate column X data from table Y.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose these are your tables; both have `ID` column, but you can't make a join on it as they have nothing in common.

```
SQL> select * from x order by id;

        ID          X
---------- ----------
         1        100
         2        200
         3        300

SQL> select * From y order by id;

I          Y
- ----------
A         10
B         20
C         30
D         40

SQL>
```

You'd want to put `Y` values (10, 20, 30, ...) into `X` column (instead of 100, 200, ...). Here's one option: use `ROWNUM` as a *fake* `ID` column which will then be used to establish join between tables. No problem in doing that because you don't really care which value goes where.

```
SQL> update x set
  2    x.x = (with
  3            a as (select id, x, rownum rn from x),
  4            b as (select id, y, rownum rn from y)
  5            select b.y
  6            from a join b on a.rn = b.rn
  7            where a.id = x.id
  8          );

3 rows updated.
```

New table `X` contents:

```
SQL> select * from x order by id;

        ID          X
---------- ----------
         1         10
         2         20
         3         30

SQL>
```